# Conditional to detect page starting

Tags: conditionals

I'd like to change the behaviour of `\section` whenever the section title occurs at the beginning of a page. So, my question is: how does LaTeX "know" that a new page is starting? How could you write a conditional for this purpose? It could be something similar to the mechanism removing a `\vspace` at the beginning of the page.

Comment: Often a box is formatted on one page and winds up on the next, so when the code runs it has no idea where it is.  You might be able to use needspace to detect whether or not it can force a page change.  BTW, does it matter it there is a top float above the \section?

Comment: it doesn't know: text including page headings is set on to a vertical "scroll" and later a page breaker takes typeset lines from there, merges it with floating figures and page head and foot and makes a page.

Comment: you can use \pdfsavepos to store the position of the section head in the aux file and then detect on the next run of latex what its vertical position was last time and adjust accordingly.

Comment: This smell to XY problem. What are you trying to solve knowing if a `\section` occurs at the beginning or elsewhere?

Comment: @Fran: basically, I asked it because it could help to force the subsequent text to align with the baseline grid (if `\beforesecskip + \aftersecskip` is not an integer amount of `\baselineskip`(for details cf. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579386/title-vertical-spacing-and-grid-alignment) I asked some time ago). Actually, exploring the idea of using \pdfsavepos by @DavidCarlisle (thanks!), I found that the command `\vskipnextgrid` of Markus Kohm's `gridset` could possibly do the job (it's a pity that it's just an alpha version...).

Comment: Then maybe some other packagesin the  [typeset grid topic in CTAN] (https://ctan.org/topic/typeset-grid ) could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\pdfsavepos` to store the position of the section head in the aux file and then detect on the next run of latex what its vertical position was last time and adjust accordingly.